# django - unexpected behavior when "updating" property in instance of model

Tags: python, database, django

I'm relativly new to django and found this behavior:

In my views.py i have defined the following function that gets some json and updates some values of a record.

```
def put_global_vars(request, lab_id):
    lab = Lab.objects.get(id=lab_id)
    response = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        array = simplejson.loads(request.POST['result'])
        response += 'success'
        data = array['array']
        lab.services = data[0]
        lab.states = data[1]
        lab.node_set = data[2]
        lab.selected_nodes = data[3]
        lab.is_slided = data[4]
        lab.is_select_enabled = data[5]
        print lab.is_select_enabled
    lab.save()
    lab = Lab.objects.get(id=lab_id)
    print lab.is_select_enabled
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'response' : response}), mimetype='application/json')
```

The problem is that apparently is not saving the new property values.
For the first print statement it returns `True`, and it is what is should be.
But for the second print statement it returns `False`, that is not what i expect.
However `False` is the default value for that property. Is that related?
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `lab` variable is out of `if` scope when you saved it, so its value isn't being updated. So your solution should be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        array = simplejson.loads(request.POST['result'])
        response += 'success'
        data = array['array']
        lab.services = data[0]
        lab.states = data[1]
        lab.node_set = data[2]
        lab.selected_nodes = data[3]
        lab.is_slided = data[4]
        lab.is_select_enabled = data[5]
        print lab.is_select_enabled
        lab.save()
```

Comment: how? in models.py is_select_enabled is defined as `is_select_enabled=False`

Comment: in models.py the field should be `not` like: `models.BooleanField(editable=False)`

Comment: i changed models.py to `is_select_enabled=models.BooleanField(default=False)

Comment: but still same result

Comment: i just commented out lab.save() hehe :) now it works. thanks for ur fast reply. was really helpfull. the problem was in the models.py